# Re-trigger Css3 Keyframe animations on jQuery/Javascript time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, timedelay

This has been bugging me for a while now, any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've been using css3 keyframe animations, I've run into a problem, I'm trying to get my animation  element to re-trigger after a timed delay, all the other questions are asking and receiving similar ones for `onclick` triggers.

`http://codepen.io/stoikerty/pen/mBAcs` is a great example, just how would it be done on a time delay

> **Document**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> **Div Element on document**

```
<div id="bannerImg" class="banner-RunAnimation"></div>
```

> **Animation settings**

```
.banner-RunAnimation{-webkit-animation: bannerImg-animation1 3s 0s 1 ease-in-out, bannerImg-animation2 5s 5s 1 ease-out forwards;}
```

> **Animation keyframes**

```
@-webkit-keyframes bannerImg-animation1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bannerImg-animation2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-150px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

> **Script**

```
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById('bannerImg');

    elem.style.WebkitDuration = '2000ms';
    elem.style.WebkitAnimationName = 'bannerImg-animation1';
</script>
```

Comment: Cobine the two animations into one and make it loop forever?

Comment: Nope that won't work, this is one element that once it has played through stops and another timed animation starts afterwards. I need the timed reset so I can time the animations, after all animations have finished then reset and start again, think of a flash banner style thing in css3.

Comment: Why won't you just modify the example you provided? http://jsfiddle.net/Misiur/ePhTw/ - simply create another class and then toggle it on timer